# Flyway cant find migrations in default location when deployed on kura osgi environment

Tags: osgi, flyway, kura

I've work with flyway with most of my project before and never had such issue. I blame osgi.
Lets get into details:

I have flyway configured such way:

```
Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().locations("classpath:db/migration").dataSource(url, user, password).load();
flyway.migrate();
```

And its refused to work and I am getting an error:

> Flyway Community Edition 6.4.3 by Redgate Unable to resolve location
> classpath:db/migration. Note this warning will become an error in
> Flyway 7.

I've checked and I have migration sql files in root of jar file as expected *.jar/db/migration/.
But flyway cant find those.
Previously I was using OS file path:

```
Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().locations("filesystem:/opt/db/migrations").dataSource(url, user, password).load();
```

Which was working correctly.

My jar is packaged into dp file bundle for osgi platform, and I think it is a problem, as osgi runtime cant find via classpath. I could not find any solution over the network.
I found such one:
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1626

which is horror for me. I do not understand why such important feature is labeled with:

> Someday-Maybe

I am asking You for any suggestions.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

If db/migration is in your own bundle then you could try.

```
Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
  .locations("classpath:db/migration")
  .dataSource(url, user, password).load();
flyway.migrate();
```

This way you tell the library to use the classloader of your class which is the classloader of your bundle. (At least I hope so. I am not familiar with Flyway, just checked what the API might offer).